# Проект не видит библиотеки при установке через pip

Tags: python, pycharm, pip

Вообщем, прогаю в `PyCharm`. Когда пытаюсь установить какую-нибудь библиотеку через терминал пайчармовский ничего не работает, вроде и установилось, но в проекте пишет, что нет. Вопросов много: если уж установилось, то куда, и можно ли как-то поменять `pip` на тот, который действует и внутри проекта

Comment: C:\Users\ВашЮзернейм\PycharmProjects\НазваниеВашегоПроекта\venv\Lib - проверяйте в данном каталоге, установилось ли туда нужная либа, если там пусто, переустанавливайте `pycharm`

Comment: Зачем переустанавливать. Надо перед установкой войти в виртуальное окружение, а потом уже pip. А установилось в глобальное место. Запустите терминал не в PyCharm и наберите pip list - найдёте всё, что поставили

Comment: @Виктор, ну я нашел в cmd эти библ-и? а дальше то что? А еще есть такая проблема, у меня не создается venv в проектах, постоянно вылазит ошибка. Поэтому у меня все проекты внутри одного, в котором работает, если создаю новый, то ничего не запускается

Comment: Давай по порядку. В pycharm console какого вида приглашение к вводу?

Comment: @Виктор Ну написано: PS C:\Users\<>\PycharmProjects\Проект>
Сам pip работает нормально вроде, только я не понимаю, где он находится..

Comment: venv\Scripts\activate  Должно появиться (имя) C:\Users\...>  Тут уже pip ....   Потом можно venv\Scripts\deactivate

Comment: Вот именно, что нет этой папки venv, когда я пытаюсь его создать мне пишет ошибку, я не понимаю в чем проблема..

Comment: Ищите на уровень выше. Какую ошибку пишет-то и как вы её создаёте

Comment: Тут читайте https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html#python_create_virtual_env

Comment: Вообщем, у меня несколько версий питона, я в них запутался, в пафах тоже запутался, новый проект с venv`ом и новой версией питона создал, вроде пока что все норм работает..

Comment: Но все же вопрос с этим pipом остался, в терминале pycharm`а все тот же pip, старый, не знаю точно откуда. В новом проекте свой venv, и библиотеки, но pip list показывает кучу библиотек, которых в этом проекте не было.

Comment: Попробовал venv\Scripts\activate. Появилась ошибка в терминале: Невозможно загрузить файл C:\Users\Ilmir\PycharmProjects\NewProject\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1, так как выполнение сценариев отключено в этой системе.
строка:1 знак:1
+ .\venv\Scripts\activate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : Ошибка безопасности: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

Comment: Притом ошибка, как оказалось, только в pycharm terminalе, в cmd все ок, Просто переустановлю pycharm наверно, cmd буду пользоваться

Comment: @Виктор Огромное спасибо за помощь!